# cURL receives response from POST method but Java code doesn't

Tags: java, curl, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a cURL script performing the task of uploading an xml file to a remote server and in response, receiving data and saving it to another xml file.

The script in cURL is like this.

```
curl -d @C:\MyUtility\Request\testRequest.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml" http://xml.example.com:4000/FilePickup -o C:\MyUtility\Response\testResponse.xml
```

Now, I am trying to implement that using apache's commons-HTTPClient API. Specifically maven artifact with groupID `commons-httpclient` atrifactID `commons-httpclient` and version `3.1`.

Here is the code for the same.

```
public static void generateResponse(File requestFile, String strURL, File responseFile) {
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = null;
        try {
            post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(new FileInputStream(requestFile), requestFile.length()));
            post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            int result = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
            System.out.println(result);

            if (result == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
                System.out.println("Remote location not accessible through POST method.");
                post.getResponseBodyAsString();
            } else if (result == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE) {
                System.out.println("Problem accessing remote location.");
                System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
            } else {
                bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(post.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String readLine;
                while (((readLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)) {
                    sb.append(readLine);
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(responseFile);
                fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
                bufferedreader.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Now, the issue is, when I use the cURL script, from the same machine, for the same file, the response is received and the responseFile.xml is generated. While through Java code, I get response `result` to be `501` only which is `HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`.

As far as I researched in cURL, the `-d` arguement adds data to the request and determines request method `POST` by default unless the `-G` argument is given for overriding to `GET` method. So in my cURL script, I figured it is using `POST` method for request and it is getting response for that. Why not in the Java code?

Can anyone help with this please? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It appears the Content-Type in your code is not identical to the Content-Type in your `curl` command.  Whether that makes a difference depends on the input file's encoding and whether it has non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I tried using the same Content-Type. Didn't work as well. Also, my files contain only regular ASCII characters.